# Data race inside OpenMP critical section

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, openmp, race-condition

My code is threaded using OpenMP. I'm now using the *Intel Inspector* to check for data races between the threads and I got some inside a critical section.

The relevant code is:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(current_num_threads) default(none) shared(max_particle_radius_,min_particle_radius_,...)
        {
            double thread_max_radius = max_particle_radius_;
            double thread_min_radius = min_particle_radius_;

#pragma omp for schedule(static)
            for (ID i = 0; i<n_particles_; ++i) {
                 // ...
                 thread_max_radius = max(thread_max_radius, radius);
                 thread_min_radius = min(thread_min_radius, radius);
                 // ...
            }
#pragma omp critical (reduce_minmax_radius)
            {
                 max_particle_radius_ = max(max_particle_radius_, thread_max_radius);
                 min_particle_radius_ = min(min_particle_radius_, thread_min_radius);
            }
        }
```

The two `max_particle_radius_` and `min_particle_radius_` are actually members of the same class this code is executed in, so basically they are automatically shared in the parallel region.

The intel inspector then gives me following error, which I can't really understand:

[image: Data race description from intel inspector]

How can there be a data race, if only one thread at the time can enter the critical section? Am I missing something about how OpenMP works?

Comment: why don't you just declare `reduction(max: max_particle_radius_), reduction(min: min_particle_radius_)` at your `pragma omp parallel` level and get rid of all the additional manual part surrounding your `for` loop?

Comment: I was looking for that, but was not entirely sure if that was only supported in Fortran, or also in C++. Still, it would be actually nice to understand why my approach would lead to a data race.

Comment: It's most likely a false positive. Try removing the name of the critical section and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @HristoIliev You're probably right. Removing the name of the critical section does not fix it though.

Comment: Could it just be that the inspector doesn't understand that max and min are associative and commutative? I mean if that were not the case, this would still be a data race I guess, as the order in which threads execute the critical section is not always the same.

Comment: @Paul Yesterday I indeed tried to hard code the `max` and `min` functions using the ternary operator but it still gave the data race. Am I wrong in stating that this is the proof that that's not the problem?

Comment: I don't think that it matters if you define max and min yourself or not. The tools probably don't have the necessary logic to know about commutativeness and associativeness. That being said, this may not be the problem here, as pretty much anything that should be wrapped in a critical section would be reported as a data race by this definition. I'm just saying that a generic (as in maybe not associative/commutative) reduction inside a critical section could still be seen as data race, as the result could depend on the order in which threads reach the critical section.